# lambda in python can iterate dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have an interview recently. The interviewer asked me the ways to iterate dict in `python`. I said all the ways use **for** statement. But he told me that how about **lambda**?

I feel confused very much and I consider lambda as an anonymity function, but how it iterates a dict? some code like this:

```
new_dict = sorted(old_dict.items(), lambda x: x[1]) # sorted by value in dict
```

But in this code, the lambda is used as a function to provide the compared key. What do you think this question?

Comment: without a lot more context, we can't tell you whether your interviewer had any idea of what he asked.

Comment: Also, note that using `map` and `sorted` and other iterating functions (`enumerate`, etc.) will also use `for`, somewhere under the hood.

Comment: @jonrsharpe usually those functions are written in C and strictly speaking don't use Python `for`.

Comment: Very strange question from the interviewer

Comment: @Andrey this is true (for CPython), but it's not clear whether that was a relevant distinction.

Comment: @MarcusMüller his word means that lambda is a way to iterate dict.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it just makes your statement not universally true and considering that CPython is by far most popular implementation it makes it practically mostly false.

Comment: @Andrey note that I (carefully) *didn't* say *"Python `for`"*, just `for`. It's pointless getting into that level of detail when what we're really discussing is what the OP thought they interviewer was asking (which either or both of them may not really have understood). My point was that there is some form of `for` loop (and therefore `O(n)` operation) going on somewhere, so calling that distinct is somewhat meaningless.

Comment: @chyooCHENG it doesn't make too much sense. Either he worded it differently or worded it poorly or s/he doesn't understand lambdas themself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you can iterate over iterable with `while` or even with recursion. My point is that if you want to be precise you should not make such assumptions on implementations of functions.

Comment: @Andrey that's a good point; in many ways, of course, a Python `for` loop is just a `while` that `break`s on `StopIteration`.

Comment: @Andrey I think so. He said he is good at php ... so ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't iterate with `lambda`. There are following ways to iterate an iterable object in Python:

1. `for` statement (your answer)
2. Comprehension, including list `[x for x in y]`, dictionary `{key: value for key, value in x}` and set `{x for x in y}`
3. Generator expression: `(x for x in y)`
4. Pass to function that will iterate it (`map`, `all`, `itertools` module)
5. Manually call `next` function until `StopIteration` happens.

Note: 3 will not iterate it unless you iterate over that generator later. In case of 4 it depends on function.

For iterating specific collections like dict or list there can be more techniques like `while col: remove element` or with index slicing tricks.

Now `lambda` comes into the picture. You can use lambdas in some of those functions, for example: `map(lambda x: x*2, [1, 2, 3])`. But lambda here has nothing to do with iteration process itself, you can pass a regular function `map(func, [1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: If you're going to separate comprehensions from generator expressions, you should include dictionary and set comprehensions. And note that generator expressions/comprehensions do include `for` as part of their syntax.

Comment: @jonrsharpe they include `for` but OP explicitly said "for statement" so he didn't just said "for keyword". I will include dict/set comprehensions but it is not about separating comprehensions from generator expressions. Those two are principally different in nature while dict/set ones are of same nature as list.

Comment: There are more ways than just 4.  For example, you could use `while d: d.popitem()`

Comment: You may be able to iterate using lambdas if you write a Y combinator. Pythonic? God no.

Comment: @wim I meant how to iterate iterable, yeah for specific collections there are more ways

Comment: {key: value for key, value in x} not working! I tried {key: value for key, value in dict1} for interating dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}. I get "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack".

Comment: @NamitaMaharanwar: if you iterate through a dict like that, you only iterate through the keys, not key-value-tuples. Iterate `dict.iteritems()` instead.

Answer (score 12):

You can iterate dict using lambda like this:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
values = map(lambda key: d[key], d.keys())
```

Comment: Strictly, `map` is iterating over the dictionary

Comment: You better use function without side effects in map.

Comment: values =d.values() !!

Answer (score 1):

Using a plain `lambda` to iterate anything in Python sounds very wrong. Certainly the most Pythonic method to iterate sequences and collections is to use list comprehensions and generator expressions like @Andrey presented.

If the interviewer was leaning on the more theoretical/Computer Sciencey answers, it is worth noting that using lambdas to iterate *is quite possible*, although I must stress that this is not Pythonic nor useful at any context other than academic exercises:

```
# the legendary Y combinator makes it possible
# to let nameless functions recurse using an indirection
Y = lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y: f(lambda *args: y(y)(*args)))
# our iterator lambda
it = lambda f: lambda Lst: (Lst[0], f(Lst[1:])) if Lst else None
# see it in action:
Y(it)([1,2,3])
=> (1, (2, (3, None)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`lambda` itself doesn't iterate anything. As you thought, it just defines an anonymous function - aside from the syntactic rule about only being able to have an expression, a `lambda` does nothing more than a similar function made using `def`. The code inside the lambda might iterate something, but only in the same ways as any other function might use (provided they are expressions, and so valid inside a `lambda`).

In the example you mention using `sorted`, the key function is called on each element of the list being sorted - but it is `sorted` itself that does this, and which does the iteration. When you provide a key function, `sorted` does something broadly similar to this:

```
def sorted(seq, key):
    decorated = [(key(elem), i) for i, elem in enumerate(seq)]
    # Sort using the normal tuple lexicographic comparisons
    decorated.sort()
    return [seq[i] for _,i in decorated]
```

As you can see, `sorted` does the iteration here, not the `lambda`. Indeed, there is no reason why the key *has* to be a lambda - any function (or any callable) will do as far as `sorted` is concerned.

---

At the lowest level, there is only really one way to iterate a dict (or, indeed, any other iterable) in Python, which is to use the *iterator protocol*. This is what the `for` loop does behind the scenes, and you could also use a `while` statement like this:

```
it = iter(my_iterable)
while True:
    try:
        val = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        # Run else clause of for loop
        break
    else:
        # Run for loop body
```

The comments in this aren't strictly part of the iterator protocol, they are instead part of the `for` loop (but having at least a loop body in there is mostly the point of iterating in the first place).

Other functions and syntax that consume iterables (such as list, set and dict comprehensions, generator expressions or builtins like `sum`, `sorted` or `max`) all use this protocol, by either:

- Using a Python `for` loop,
- Doing something like the above `while` loop (especially for modules written in C),
- Delegating to another function or piece of syntax that uses one of these

---

A class can be made so that its instances *become* iterable in either of two ways:

- Provide the iterator protocol directly. You need a method called `__iter__` (called by `iter`), which returns an *iterator*. That iterator has a method called `__next__` (just `next` in Python 2) which is called by `next` and returns the value at the iterator's current location and advances it (or raises `StopIteration` if it is already at the end); or
- Implement part of the *sequence protocol* (which means behaving like a list or tuple). For forward iteration, it is sufficient to define `__getitem__` in such a way that doing `my_sequence[0]`, `my_sequence[1]`, up until `my_sequence[n-1]` (where `n` is the number of items in the sequence), and higher indexes raise an error. You usually want to define `__len__` as well, which is used when you do `len(my_sequence)`.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary iteration using lambda

```
dct = {1: '1', 2 : '2'}
```

Iterating over Dictionary using lambda:

```
map(lambda x : str(x[0]) + x[1], dct.iteritems())
```

here x[0] is the key
and x[1] is the value

Result : 
['11', '22']

Filtering on Dictionary using lambda:

```
filter(lambda x : x[0] > 1, dct.iteritems())
```

Result :
[(2, '2')]

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Answer (score 0):

The best way to iterate dict in python is:

```
dic ={}

iter_dic = dic.iteritems().next
iter_dic()
...
iter_dic()
```

But you can build it with lambda func:

```
iter_dic = lambda dic: dic.keys()[0],dic.pop(dic.keys()[0])
iter_dic(dic)
...
iter_dic(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could we say

```
count = {8: 'u', 4: 't', 9: 'z', 10: 'j', 5: 'k', 3: 's'}
count_updated = dict(filter(lambda val: val[0] % 3 == 0,
                     count.items()))
```

is iterating Dictionary with Lambda function?

It will produce:
   {8: 'u', 4: 't', 9: 'z', 10: 'j', 5: 'k', 3: 's'}
   {9: 'z', 3: 's'}

from [Python dictionary filter + Examples](https://pythonguides.com/python-dictionary-filter/#:%7E:text=By%20using%20the%20filter%20and%20the%20Python%20lambda,item%3A%20item%20is%20None%2C%20to_dictionary.items%20%28%29%29%29%20print%20%28non_val%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
newlist = sorted(old_dict, key=lambda d: d['name'])
```

this way easily sorted, using lambda

Example:

```
list_to_be_sorted=[{'Name':"Murali", 'Age':34 },{'Name':"Mangesh",'Age':40},{'Name':"Dimple King",'Age':49}]

new_dict=sorted(list_to_be_sorted,key=lambda by_name:by_name['Name'])
#new_dict = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda d: d['Name'])
print(new_dict)
```

output:

> [{'Name': 'Dimple King', 'Age': 49}, {'Name': 'Mangesh', 'Age': 40},
> {'Name': 'Murali', 'Age': 34}]