# dictionary iterable of all key and list value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable

I'm looking for a method on a dictionary (or a simple solution) that can return key, value combinations.

```
dictionary = {'foo': ['bar', 'baz'],
              'spam': ['eggs']}
```

What I want are combinations of the key value pairs that also unpack the lists.

ex:

```
'foo', 'bar'
'foo', 'baz'
'spam', 'eggs'

tuples = []
for key in dictionary:
    for value in dictionary.get(key):
        tuples.append((key, value))
```

The above works, but I'm curious if there is an existing itertool or dictionary method that can replicate these loops.

Comment: this might be useful to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077274/lambda-in-python-can-iterate-dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> dictionary
{'foo': ['bar', 'baz'], 'spam': ['eggs']}
>>> [(k, v) for k, l in dictionary.items() for v in l]
[('foo', 'bar'), ('foo', 'baz'), ('spam', 'eggs')]
```

Of course this also works as a generator or in whatever other context you need it.

Comment: Thank you! Especially like the recommendation to make it a generator. Much cleaner than the verbose double for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a built in feature, but you can achieve this very easily.

```
mydict = {'foo': ['bar', 'baz'],
          'spam': ['eggs']}

for key, value in ((k,v) for (k, vs) in mydict.items() for v in vs):
     print(key, value)
```

Or to get them as a list

```
items = [(k, v) for (k,vs) in mydict.items() for v in vs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for key in dictionary:
    for item in dictionary[key]:
        print key, item
```

Answer (score 0):

Another **easy** way for *beginners*:

```
dictionary = {'foo': ['bar', 'baz'], 'spam': ['eggs']}

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    for item in value:
        print((key, item))
```

**note that** using parenthesis for creating tuple on output.

Answer (score 0):

Using [yield](https://docs.python.org/2.4/ref/yield.html) to write a generator.

Instead of having the outputs populated in memory as a list. unpack function creates the required output on go, which is very useful if there are huge number of keys in the dictionary.

```
mydict = {'foo': ['bar', 'baz'],
      'spam': ['eggs']}

def unpack(dictionay):
    for key, values in dictionay.items():
        for val in values:
            yield key,val 

for k, v in unpack(mydict):
    print k, v
```